# How Fragile Is DB if I Upload Completely Updated Files

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

My localhost website is now just about perfect, can I just production that without worrying about Plugin and Theme updates dependent on DB?

Answer (score 0):

Plugins and themes **are** dependent on the database!
I suggest you to:

1. Upload the complete website. At this stage wordpress will start the usual setup from scratch.
2. Install and activate this plugin: https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db
3. Sync local db to production

Comment: Thanks, but I'm very very very manuallying it now... Pretty much repeating my steps that I did on localhost :/ 

EDIT: In a different order though :)

Comment: Amazing link, I will defenitely check that out... (y)

Comment: It totally changed my workflow, it makes db syncing a breeze

Comment: I needed something like this long timessss ago. Will see if it's still worth it, just wish these ThemeForest theme developers will keep and stay to standard :/